# Assign value of int variable to int pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting, int, assign

I have the following C function used in an **embedded software project**. It's also used for the **verification of the hardware** and not in production.

```
void reg_read(int addr) {
   int result;
   int* reg_addr = (int*)(addr); // I cast the value of the addr variable to the reg_addr pointer hoping that it would point to the address stored in addr
   result = (*reg_addr); // this should trigger a read transaction on the AXI interface of the ARM CPU that I'm simulating
}
// later on...in the main function
reg_read(0x08000704);
```

The embedded software runs in a simulated environment(using QEMU+SystemC) and I can see if the AXI read transaction happens or not. In this case it doesn't happen.

However, if I assign a constant value to the pointer like `int* reg_addr = (int*)0x08000704;` then the AXI transaction happens.

I assume the compiler generates different instructions in each case. I also tried to declare reg_addr as `volatile int* reg_addr;` but it didn't work either.

Is there a portable and compliant way of casting the value of an int variable to an int pointer?

Comment: `uintptr_t` and friends.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Make it an answer?

Comment: @EugeneSh.'s answer is spot on. Try that, if it doesn't work I also have the hunch that in this code the compiler could potentially optimize and never actually read from the location you've specified.

Comment: What happens if you make `result` volatile, as well as `volatile int* reg_addr;`? I am thinking the compiler, seeing it did not need `result`, decided it did not need to the value from `*reg_addr`. That value was volatile, so the compiler is required to read it if it needs it—but it did not need it. Making `result` volatile forces the compiler to write it, which means it needs the value, which forces it to read `*reg_addr`.

Comment: Your question is *"Is there a portable and compliant way of casting the value of an int variable to an int pointer?"* and the answer is: "no". Read the standard. Conversion of an integer to a pointer is *implementation defined*. The compiler manuals do tell how it happens.

Comment: Thank you all for the useful comments! I found a workaround to get it to work. Instead of assigning the address value to a pointer variable I casted it like this `result = (*((volatile uint32 *)(addr)));`. Not sure if this is portable and not even sure why it works likes this and the other way. It's the result of trial and error. I don't want to publish it as an answer until I fully understand what's going on. I am using the gcc compiler for ARM to compile this. uint32 is a typedef for `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is:

> Is there a portable and compliant way of casting the value of an int
>   variable to an int pointer?

There is not.  Summed up from the comments:

> Conversion of an integer to a pointer is implementation defined - Antti Haapala

It was suggested that you use uintptr_t or similar which is a good suggestion from Eugene Sh.

In the example of uintptr_t

```
uintptr_t = unsigned integer type capable of holding a pointer
```

From the vadefs.h file from the Microsoft Visual C++ header file vadefs.h it is defined as:

```C++
#ifdef _WIN64
    typedef unsigned __int64  uintptr_t;
#else
    typedef unsigned int uintptr_t;
#endif
```

In this manner, if you compile for x86 it would resolve to a 32bit data type and for x64, a 64 bit data type.